# Invalid ResX file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've been developing this Frogger game so I can learn loops and sub/function procedures while using bools. So far the game has worked out nicely until I came upon an issue that returned my form to a blank Form and somehow my ResX file is screwed up

I get this warning

```
Message 1   ResX file The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.  Line 24774, position 5. cannot be parsed.        24774   0
```

And then I get this error

```
Error   2   Invalid Resx file. The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.  Line 24774, position 5. C:\Users\alex96\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Frogger\Frogger\Form1.resx    24774   5   Frogger
```

The line that the error is hinting at this in the Form1.resx file. It says Column 5 which is the / in the data closing tag. I can't build my Frogger now, and I was very close to kinking out all the bugs.

```
   </data>
```

Comment: Restore the .resx file from source control.  If you don't use any then you've learned a valuable lesson that lots of programmers need to learn the hard way.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't mess with the ResX file at all

Comment: @HansPassant Not the programmers fault. I experienced the same, and I didn't change the .resx file in any way. At some point, the IDE suddenly told me that a certain image file was too big. However, it accepted it all the time, and I didn't change it.

Comment: Also, when I try to open up the .resx file, the IDE tells me "The object reference was not set to an object instance."

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me. My solution was to create a new form (with a different name) and copy all the text from the Form1.Designer.cs file (except the class declaration) and obviously the code (Form1.cs) from it. 
Then I tried to open the new form and, as I expected, it was a copy of the one with the dead .resx file. Finally, I deleted the original form, renamed the new one, and voillá!
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. When I have access to VS again tomorrow I will try this. I will accept this answer when I see that this works. Merci beaucoup...also VB not C#